# Could not find artifact spring-boot-thin-layout:jar:1.0.27.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

More info of the error:

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) on project HelloWorldProject: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage failed: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3
with org.springframework.boot.experimental

Comment: Oh thanks, I see in the [mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-thin-layout) that version 1.0.26.RELEASE is the highest present version existing for spring-boot-thin-layout.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks, I see [in the mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-thin-layout) that version 1.0.26.RELEASE is the highest version existing for spring-boot-thin-layout.